# What does 0:({}) mean in object dump in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, object

I dumped an object in Mozilla and I got the following:

```
({
    length:1, 
    prevObject:{0:({}), context:({}), length:1}, 
    context:({}), 
    selector:"ROOT", 
    0:({})
})
```

What does `({})` mean in object notation? I understand that `{}` means an object but what do
the round braces signify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `{}` could also mean an empty block, for example:  in the console, you need to type `({})` to mean an object.

Comment: Ah ok... got it. Thanks for answering. Somehow I didnt notice the notification from stackoverflow :)